# dynamically changing node renderering in tree

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When I call [**itemClick()**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel) in an **Ext.tree.Panel** I would like to render some arbitrary nodes.

Lets say, when I click on a node I want to highlight all of its children yellow :

[image]

simples.

I know how to render the *clicked* node. That's easy :

```
itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

    //HTMLElement
    item.style.color="RED";
```

Item is just a **HTMLElement** which can get its style changed.

I also managed to figure out that I can also access data from the store like so :

```
itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

    //View --> store
    dv.store.data.items[4]
```

The data items are just the **Ext.data.Model** objects *i think*. I can't see any hook where I can add styling to the item objects however :(

I also looked at doing an 'up' query and calling **findChild(..)** on tree panel:

```
itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {


    //Ext.data.NodeInterface
    var panel = dv.up('panel');
    var rn = panel.getRootNode();

    var r = rn.findChild("name", "MYNODE");

    r.data.cls = 'my_class';
```

There is a cls 'hook' where I can set class values. However the rendering does not seem to happen. Also the findChild method only returns one value, and there is no findChildren (which is really perplexing. *Why would ExtJS ommit something like that?* )

This event callback method really puzzles me. I somehow need a link between the HTMLElement and the data items or store. All these approaches seem to lead to a dead end for me.

**UPDATE :** 
In the third example I can call panel.getView().refresh(); and this will update the UI. So now the only problem I have is finding a method like getChildren(..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  solved my problem by first getting my panel and then root node. Then on my root node I called the **eachChild()** function.

I needed to pass in an a recursive function. This recursive function looked for nodes I'm interested in (using searchTerm), and then it could set a **cls** value. At the end I run **panel.getView().refresh(),** and it all works splendidly.

```
itemclick: function (dv, record, item, index, e) {



    var panel = dv.up('panel');
    var rn = panel.getRootNode();

    var traverseTree = function (c) {

        if (c.data.name == traverseTree.searchTerm) {
            c.data.cls = 'myClass';
        }else {
            c.data.cls = '';
        }

        if (c.childNodes.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < c.childNodes.length; i++) {

                var node = c.childNodes[i];

                traverseTree(node)
            }
        }
    };

    traverseTree.searchTerm = "StringToMatch";
    rn.eachChild(traverseTree, rn);
    panel.getView().refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for getting the child nodes may be the following code might help you

```
   var nodeRef = this.items.items[0]   //this will give you the first root node.
   var node = nodeRef.node;
   var childrenNodes = node.childNodes;
```

The above(*this* in the above code refers to your treepanel) will give you the immediate child nodes.
Hope this helps you.Also take a look at this [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?80955-Treepanel-node.childNodes-does-not-get-the-child-nodes) from sencha forums.